Which packages do configure the scaling_governor?
I am just trying to figure out why some Ubuntu desktop systems (no laptops, no batteries, just desktop systems) have the governor
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_governor
set to powersave, and some have set to schedutil
although cpufrequtils are not installed.
Which packages/units/daemons do set the governor?

The default CPU frequency scaling governor is a function of the processor make and model. For Intel processors it is also a function of if HWP (HardWare Pstate) control is both available and enabled. When no CPU frequency scaling driver override is specificed on the kernel boot command line: For Intel Processors without HWP or if disabled, the default will be schedutil; For Intel Processors with HWP and with it enabled, the default will be powersave; AMD I don't know. I do not know the answer to your actual question, because I never use those daemons and utilities.
